# How to find css files in Laravel 8

Tags: css, laravel

The picture beneath shows my Laravel project structure.

[image: Laravel project structure]

In my file `head.blade.php` I have tried the following things to include `resources/css/general.css`:

```
#1
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="{{ asset('css/general.css') }}">
#2
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="{{ asset('/css/general.css') }}">
#3
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="{{ asset('/resources/css/general.css') }}">
#4
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="{{ asset('resources/css/general.css') }}">
```

None of the four options work, the CSS file does not get found. However, `<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="{{ asset('css/app.css') }}">` Does get found for some reason... Why does `app.css` gets found but `general.css` not while they're in the same folder?

The following commands:

```
npm install
npm run dev
```

returns the following:

```
> dev
> npm run development


> development
> mix


● Mix █████████████████████████ sealing (87%)
 code generation




● Mix █████████████████████████ done (99%) plugins
 WebpackBar:done







✔ Mix
  Compiled successfully in 613.02ms



   Laravel Mix v6.0.37


✔ Compiled Successfully in 593ms
┌────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┬─────────┐
│                                                               File │ Size    │
├────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┼─────────┤
│                                                         /js/app.js │ 606 KiB │
│                                                        css/app.css │ 1 bytes │
└────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┴─────────┘
webpack compiled successfully
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`asset()` is used to reference files in the `public` directory. Typically you would copy / do some processing in your `webpack.mix.js` file to get the files over to the public directory.

Ex in `webpack.mix.js`:

```
mix.postCss("resources/css/example.css", "public/css/example.css");
```

Copies the `example.css` file to the public directory as `example.css` (once you run `npm`)

Then in your blade you could reference like:
`asset('css/example.css')`

Comment: Adding it to `webpack.mix.js` and rerunning `npm run dev` works indeed. Is there a way to include all the CSS-files from a specific directory? Like `*.css`?

Comment: You can copy multiple files. See https://laravel-mix.com/docs/6.0/copying-files

Answer (score 0):

move the CSS file location to Public file if u want to use asset()